# SAP Full-stack web IDE Build error

Tags: node.js, sapui5

I have been having trouble with my SAP Full-stack Web IDE deployment to SAP Cloud Platform.

I'm getting the following messages:

> 11:43:36 PM (DIBuild) Build of /OrderEntry in progress
>
> 11:43:38 PM (DIBuild) [INFO] Retrieving source code
>   [INFO] Preparing node environment[INFO] Node environment ready
>
> 11:43:44 PM (DIBuild) [INFO] Installing node dependencies
>
> 11:43:53 PM (DIBuild) npm ERR! code E418npm ERR! 418 I'm a teapot: archiver@2.1.1
>
> 11:43:57 PM (DIBuild) npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
>
> npm ERR! /mnt/npm_cache/_logs/2018-05-28T21_43_51_836Z-debug.log

Weird thing is that "archiver@2.1.1" is not always the dependency that errs out. Sometimes it's "gruntfile@1.0.12" and I've seen one other one as well.

Anyone know how get to the error log mentioned? Also, maybe it's just the Web IDE being buggy since it only recently went into production? Driving me crazy...

Comment: Heh. Never seen it in the wild but http error code 418 "I'm a teapot" is an [april fools joke](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Status/418) from 1998. Regardless, it seems like a connection issue? What does gruntfile/package.json say.

Comment: Hi Jorg,

My gruntfile is:
`module.exports = function(grunt) {
 "use strict";
 grunt.loadNpmTasks("@sap/grunt-sapui5-bestpractice-build");
 grunt.registerTask("default", [
  "lint",
  "clean",
  "build"
 ]);
};`

And my package is:
`{
  "name": "OrderEntry",
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "description": "",
  "private": true,
  "devDependencies": {
    "@sap/grunt-sapui5-bestpractice-build": "1.3.55"
  }
}
`

The part that's frustrating (and leads me to believe my new error is beyond my control as well) is that I've only changed minor UI code since the last build

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the problem isn't webide.

seems to be a global issue 
https://github.com/npm/npm/issues/20791

It is fixed now

Comment: Thanks Jakob - I had it working for a bit yesterday, but today am getting this one... 

`npm ERR! code Z_BUF_ERROR
npm ERR! errno -5
npm ERR! zlib: unexpected end of file`


I browsed the npm github issues list for this but didn't see anything. Should I submit this one as well?